# How change the background color for a blank cell in QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qt4, qtablewidget, qt4.8, qtablewidgetitem

If a cell have some data, using

```
tableWidget->item(8,0)->setBackgroundColor(Qt::red);
```

to change the background color will work, but if a cell is blank it will fail.

Answer (score 40):

You cannot set the background color of a cell unless it contains a `QTableWidgetItem` (as the background color is a property of the item).

So you need to populate your `QTableWidget` with empty items first. In your example, create the item before you attempt to set the background color.

```
tableWidget->setItem(8, 0, new QTableWidgetItem);
tableWidget->item(8, 0)->setBackground(Qt::red);
```

Please also note that you should use `setBackground` instead of `setBackgroundColor` as the latter is deprecated.

Comment: Fixed a similar problem for me. Any idea why this works and `->background.setColor()` does not?